# Is it possible, and advisable, to submit a web SITE to the Chrome web store?

Tags: google-chrome, website

Is the Chrome web store just for native web apps, or hybrid apps, or can web sites be submitted, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your questions are answered on the [Google support pages for the webstore](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/1047776?hl=en)

The [guide for developers](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/faq) has even more detail.

Comment: Based on what I read there, I would say "no" (web sites need not apply); I wouldn't have thought of it, even, except that something in "The Modern Web" by Peter Gasston made me think that possibly web sites could indeed be promoted in this way.